# Script for Monitoring Apache log file behaviour

Tags: apache, logging, monitoring

I m looking for a script which monitors apache log file and alerts the admin if there is a "GET 500" string comes or the apache log file itself stops getting new entries from a particular range of IP address.

Answer (score 1):

you can use M/Monit to monitor Apache logs (and any other logs if you want). You can install and configure it on Ubuntu following the tutorial from here [How to monitor Symfony and Apache logs with M/Monit](http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2016/01/12/how-to-monitor-symfony-and-apache-logs-with-mmonit/), just ignore the symfony2 part and replace the string from `if match "error" then alert` with your `GET 500` one.